# How to show Selected feature by RFE while using shap-hypetune BoostRFE?

Tags: python, xgboost, shap

I'm following the guide at https://github.com/cerlymarco/shap-hypetune/blob/main/notebooks/XGBoost_usage.ipynb for my thesis, and I need to print the name of the variables that are saved or removed at each step (every variable represents a physical quantity).
I have started with a base XGBoost with a set of 17 features that I want to reduce and see, for each step, how some metrics (for example roc_auc) evolves.

```
XGBoost = xgb.sklearn.XGBClassifier()
model=BoostRFE(XGB, min_features_to_select=8, importance_type='shap_importances')
```

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: To get the selected features you can simply do `model.support_` . `support_` is the mask of selected features. In this way, if your data is a pandas dataframe you get the name of the selected features: `X.columns[model.support_]`